# Error installing application to the ../share/applications/ directory

Tags: software-installation, filemanager

I've tried searching with Google and StackOverflow for an installation error for the Fsearch application. My theory is that the errors stems from a change in the default location of desktop file symlinks. Build instruction for version on github: https://github.com/cboxdoerfer/fsearch/wiki/Build-instructions

```
sudo apt install git build-essential meson itstool libtool pkg-config intltool libicu-dev libpcre2-dev libglib2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev libxml2-utils
git clone https://github.com/cboxdoerfer/fsearch.git
cd fsearch
meson builddir
ninja -C builddir install
#####--------------output
ninja: Entering directory `builddir'
[0/1] Installing files.
Installing data/io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch.desktop to /usr/local/share/applications/io.github.cboxdoerfer.FSearch.desktop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meson", line 26, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/meson", line 23, in main
    return mesonmain.run(sys.argv[1:], launcher)
  File "/usr/share/meson/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 318, in run
    sys.exit(run_script_command(args[1:]))
  File "/usr/share/meson/mesonbuild/mesonmain.py", line 274, in run_script_command
    return cmdfunc(cmdargs)
  File "/usr/share/meson/mesonbuild/scripts/meson_install.py", line 393, in run
    do_install(datafilename)
  File "/usr/share/meson/mesonbuild/scripts/meson_install.py", line 212, in do_install
    install_targets(d)
  File "/usr/share/meson/mesonbuild/scripts/meson_install.py", line 330, in install_targets
    d.dirmaker.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/share/meson/mesonbuild/scripts/meson_install.py", line 36, in makedirs
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/applications'
FAILED: meson-install 
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/meson --internal install /home/david/fsearch/builddir/meson-private/install.dat
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

There is no directory by that name. There is however a directory that is populated with all the stuff that appears on the desktop :and more):

```
# Second attempt...
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:christian-boxdoerfer/fsearch-stable
sudo apt install fsearch
```

Gets an app with a magnifying glass icon but attempting to run it gets me this dialog box
[image]

```
david@davids:~/fsearch$ ls /usr/share/applications
activity-log-manager.desktop          libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop
apport-gtk.desktop                    light-locker-settings.desktop
apturl.desktop                        logout.desktop
audacity.desktop                      masterpdfeditor5.desktop
bamf-2.index                          mimeinfo.cache
beersmith3.desktop                    monodoc-http.desktop
blueman-adapters.desktop              mono-runtime-common.desktop
blueman-manager.desktop               mono-runtime-terminal.desktop
bluetooth-sendto.desktop              mount-archive.desktop
lonmg list elided
```

So my question is where should I be looking in the source code or config files of the Fsearch package to change the assumed destination to what it was for Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install the application? `/usr/local/share/applications` seems like it would be appropriate for an application installed outside of the package system (i.e. not from an Ubuntu repository). Installers typically create directories as required - provided they are run with sufficiently elevated permissions.

Comment: Tried two ways the first one above was actually the second attempt and produces the error in question.

Comment: So for the first method you would need to perform the ninja build step with `sudo`, or else configure it to install to an unprivileged directory (i.e. somewhere in your `$HOME`) - see for example [Meson and NInja build system: specifify where binaries are stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475190/meson-and-ninja-build-system-specifify-where-binaries-are-stored). Note that you would have the same issue if you change the directory to `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try it.